# Estimating different random effects based on a between-subject factor in a mixed model?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, covariance-matrix, frequentist

**Background**

I have a between-subject factor of GROUP with 2 levels (Control and Active) and a within-subject factor of TIME with 3 levels (Time1, Time2, and Time3). Code below to generate some dummy data,

```
# Loading libraries
library(tidyverse)

# Function to generate mock data for each group
generate_data_for_group <- function(group_name, start_id, n_subjects, n_timepoints, n_trials) {
  expand.grid(subject_ID = start_id:(start_id + n_subjects - 1),
              timepoint = paste0("time", 1:n_timepoints),
              trial = 1:n_trials) %>%
    mutate(group = group_name,
           y = rnorm(n_subjects * n_timepoints * n_trials))
}

# Generating data

active_data <- generate_data_for_group("active", 1, 20, 3, 30)
control_data <- generate_data_for_group("control", 21, 20, 3, 30)

# Combining data
all_data <- rbind(active_data, control_data)
```

**Issue**

I wish to,

1. Estimate the maximal random effects structure (i.e., random intercept, random slope of TIME, and their correlations) *separately* for the two groups. That is, have one covariance-variance matrix for the Control group and another for the Active group.
2. Estimate the residual variance *separately* for the two groups as well.

In `brms` both are easy to do and the function call looks like,

```
b_model <- brm(bf(y ~ timepoint * group + (timepoint | gr(subject, by = group)),
        sigma ~ Group), data = all_data)
```

**Question** - I can't seem to see anything similar in `lme4` or `nlme` (or any other frequentist R package). Would appreciate any help and advice to do this in a frequentist world.

Thank you for reading :)

Comment: Not sure but could be possible in R package glmmTMB, worth a check. Definitely it allows sigma to vary by group. Alternatively, could you fit the model with lme4 separately by group and then estimate whatever you want by g-computation/standardisation?

Comment: Thanks @Lachlan! Not really keen to run two separate models for the two groups but I'll have a look into glmmTMB. Good to hear that point 2 is possible, hopefully 1 is too!

Comment: What parameters / information do the two groups share that it's better to fit one model than two separate models?

Comment: Thanks @dipetkov, don't really want to deviate from the OP so purely want to focus on the how. Be keen to hear if you know a way of how it can be done in R or even another language.

Comment: I think it's a relevant question because you specify two completely separate models for the two groups. Since timepoint and group are both factors, the mean structure E(Y) is modeled separately. Same for the variance structure Var(Y) as you explicitly want to let all variance components be group-specific. As @Lachlan points out, you can simply fit the two groups separately. There is no loss of information this way.

Comment: That would be the easier and mathematically more satisfying approach. In principle you can also do it with the [regress](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/regress/index.html) function. You'll have to construct all the variance components "by hand". Also I'm not sure whether it will scale to a dataset of your size because of the explicit construction of those variance matrices.

Comment: Switch over to the SEM paradigm and it should be possible. It is called a multi group model. I am not 100% sure this can be done with multilevel data in lavaan without some complex coding. However, I know you can do it in Mplus.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts @dipetkov.

Thanks for the suggestion @ErikRuzek. Shall have a look at the SEM paradigm and see if it can be done in `lavaan`.